# How to detect mouse moving outside Java Popup?

Tags: java, popup, mouselistener

I'm creating the following UI in Java.

When a user hovers their mouse over a particular area on the screen, a popup appears that contains a bunch of buttons and controls.

```
PopupFactory factory = PopupFactory.getSharedInstance();
_hoverPanel = factory.getPopup( parent, panel, x, y );
_hoverPanel.show();
```

I want this panel to remain visible on the screen while the user interacts with the panel's components, but as soon as the users mouse exists the popup bounds I want the popup to hide.

I tried adding a mouselistener to the panel inside the popup but I noticed that mouseEntered only fire when I enter the panel (and not when I enter components found inside the panel) and mouseExited only fires when I exit the panel.

The problem here is that I can make the popup appear, but as soon as I move my mouse inside the panel, and then over top of a component inside the panel, mouseExited fires for the panel, and the popup hides :(

I can also move my mouse quickly inside the panel over top of a component, and mouseEntered never fires for the panel :(

How can I detect when the mouse goes inside and outside my popup panel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem (catching all mouse events while the mouse hovers over my dialog) and I solved it by wrapping the root pane of the dialog in a JLayer (javax.swing.JLayer) as shown in http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/jlayer.html#events